# I can't access an external hard drive (it has Windows 8) through my USB cable

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I know this problem can be solved by restarting with Windows 8 in an normal mode, but I don't have Windows 8 any more. I'm trying to rescue the files that I had on a laptop on which the motherboard burned out, and I can't install Windows 8 in this one: I have only Ubuntu on this machine.

I'm trying to mount it from terminal using

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdc4 at /media/bug/
```

This gives me the error message

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/bug/52B0E048B0E0345F: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb4" "/media/bug/52B0E048B0E0345F"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

How can I recover my files using Ubuntu? It says that I can mount the volume as ro, but I don't know how to do that, and I don't know it that would allow me to copy my files.

Comment: Try `sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdb4 /mnt` and then `sudo umount /mnt` at the end

Comment: It clearly tells you how to fix it `mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.`

Comment: thanks Salem but it didnt worked,and ElephantPhace i know it says that but as i said i dont know how to ive tried what in other forums said and it didnt worked, and i need to work on these files so i dont know if that's a solution or i only will get to see them as read only, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem isn't properly unmounted, probably because of the Fast Boot feature in Windows 8. You can clear this by using the command `sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sdb4`.